# C: evaluate part of the string

Tags: c, string, substring

I cant find an expression to evaluate a part of a string.

I want to get something like that:

```
if (string[4:8]=='abc') {...}
```

I started writing like this:

```
if (string[4]=='a' && string[5]=='b' && string[6]=='c') {...}
```

but if i need to evaluate a big part of string like

```
if (string[10:40] == another_string) {...}
```

then it gets to write TOO much expressions. Are there any ready-to-use solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could always use `strncmp()`, so `string[4:8] == "abc"` (which isn't C syntax, of course) could become `strncmp(string + 4, "abc", 5) == 0`.

Comment: yeah, and to be totally correct the third argument of the function (5) should actually be 3 - equal to the length of the evaluated string.

Comment: You can use `sizeof "abc" - 1` there, which might make it a bit less error-prone than counting the characters by hand for very long strings.

Comment: @Halst:  Depends on the comparison.  A [4:8] slice is not three characters long, no matter what the notation.

Answer (score 2):

The standard C library function you want is `strncmp`. `strcmp` compares two C strings and -- as is the usual pattern, the "n" version deals with limited length data items.

```
if(0==strncmp(string1+4, "abc", 4))
    /* this bit will execute if string1 
       ends with "abc" (incluing the implied null)
       after the first four chars */
```

Answer (score 0):

The [strncmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncmp/) solutions others posted are probably the best. If you don't want to use strncmp, or simply want to know how to implement your own, you can write something like this:

```
int ok = 1;
for ( int i = start; i <= stop; ++i )
    if ( string[i] != searchedStr[i - start] )
    {
        ok = 0;
        break;
    }

if ( ok ) { } // found it
else      { } // didn't find it
```